# Edit rejected because it contains too much code

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-edit

I stumbled with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631426/im-having-trouble-with-appium-eclipse-running-android-enumalator) question, which is basically a stack trace for an error, but it contains all of the stack trace like if it was a quote (also I think the title is wrong) so I decided to edit it, changing the title and removing the quote syntax from the stack trace. I was unable to complete my edit as I was presented with this error message:

[image: Error message]

My question is, how was this question which has basically the same content as my edit able to be posted and my "more readable" edit is rejected?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The quote syntax was exactly the reason why the OP managed to post his question and your edit didn't pass. When the ratio between code and text is off that warning is generated. Using the quote syntax influenced the algorithm. Your attempt to fix that revealed the error again.

I don't think that question needed an edit to be honest. It is lacking details to be answerable and is nothing more then a logcat dump. It deserves a down vote and a close flag/vote.

Don't polish turds, specially if reviewers need to review your edit as well.

If the post is *in between* and you still want to lend a helping hand you have to find and eliminate the reason the specific warning popped up. Things to look for are:

- non-latin and/or dot/slash/colon/exclamation characters in the first  paragraph
  remedied by either removing those characters or adding an introduction paragraph
- Missing a blank line right before the start of the code block.
- Two or more images without a blank line and/or html tags between them
- Valuable information in comments that can go in the post (to improve the code/text ratio)
- All spelling / grammar mistakes and "flow"/ style of the text
- Removing unneeded blank lines in the code / fix indentation (except if it is Python) (changes to code should only be done if you're 100 % you don't by accident fix the code)
- On a question:

  - Improve the title (spelling, wording, concise, no tags in it)
  - Verify the tags are correct and all tags are present
- Common sense

For the above changes you have to pay extra attention to the edit comment. Make it as clear as possible what you changed and why. You better leave a too long comment then a too short. "Fixed the post" is not going to put reviewers in the right mindset. Something like "Restructured the post to make it answerable; did A; moved B; Added stuff from comments; Removed noise; Fixed spelling;" is closer to what is the minimum requirement.

Additionally you might also want to leave a comment under the post explaining that you suggested an edit and what you left as is and invite the OP to edit further to improve their posts. The comment makes that you are easy pingable. And if a user with full edit privileges comes along that post you might get your edit approved sooner.

You have to understand that reviewing suggested edits is still a human activity and prone to errors now and then. You might still occasionally end-up with a rejected edit. The above guidance not a canonical that guarantees 100% success. It is the best I can offer to give every post the love it needs.  Make sure you pick the right battle.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks for clearing it up

Comment: What answers like this one usually leave out is a guideline what to do with posts "in between". This discussion is referenced by some duplicate-closed posts, so I'm not referring to the example of the OP of this meta thread, but to another post. I believe I'm not the only user who experiences this problem and doesn't decide towards **"close it because it is low quality [...]"** or **"don't edit it because it is pretty good the way it is and your edit contributes a negligible part"** - but one of the **cases in between.**

Comment: @HelpingHand you're welcome.